# How to limit routes in rails based on user attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I would like to limit a secific route to only "current_user.account_level == "1""

So far I have this but I can't figure out the constraints part:

`resources :users, :only => [:show, :index], :constraints =>  {}`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why can't resolve it through before_filter ?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to implement authorization in some weird way. Typically it belongs to the controller. Take a look at CanCan gem to implement it in a clean way: https://github.com/ryanb/cancan

Comment: hmmm...I think I'll roll with CanCan now, you are rite. I've avoided it before because I was able to solve the problems in a much easier way but I've done that enough times for me to think I should actually just need it.

Answer (score 0):

I think,The following will work.

```
match '/:id' => 'users#show', :constraints => { :account_level=>'1' } 
match '/' => 'users#index', :constraints => { :account_level=>'1' }
resources :users
```

In the **constraints** part, we can give regular expression. 
Eg: 
   `resources :users, :only => [:show, :index], :constraints => { ::account_level => /\1/ }`

Otherwise give the condition inside the users controller according to **current_user**.

```
if current_user.account_level == "1"
   ---code---
else
   ---code---
end
```

Comment: It doesn't. It allows everyone to see "/users"

Comment: Still a no go. What I'm not understanding from what you are trying to do is how are you scoping the "account_level"? That needs to be scoped to the "current_user" so the system know who to check the "account_level" against.

Comment: `match '/:id' => 'users#show', :constraints => { :account_level=>'1' }` `match '/' => 'users#index', :constraints => { :account_level=>'1' }`

Comment: Give the above on the top of `resources :users`